# JSON data logging to buffer and PUT to server

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a javascript function which generates JSON data at every certain  second and then PUT it to a cloud server. Now I don't want to POST in realtime, rather I want to log this data in a buffer and say after n number of data log I will PUT to cloud. For example I want to log 50 data point in 10 second and then with timestamp I will PUT to a server

Now JSON data is passed through `var fromDatan`. JSON data format is

```
{"values": [ { "at": "2014-08-17T12:00:00Z", "value": "15" }]}
```

This is a single instance which is passing through say `var fromDatan` and being PUT in cloud.

Now I want to log say n number of JSON data. ie.

```
{ "values": [ { "at": "2014-08-17T12:00:00Z", "value": "15" }, { "at": "2014-08-18T12:00:00Z", "value": "20" }, { "at": "2014-08-19T12:00:00Z", "value": "25" } ] }
```

And then I will PUT to cloud. This is my PUT code for real time which is working:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "https://abcd.com",
                headers: {
                    "X-API-KEY": "23dq3dq3ddbb16a7956e6f7a",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                type: "PUT",
                data: fromDatan,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }
                });
```

So please let me know how to do this. Help me out

Answer (score 3):

the code that runs every second should do:

```
fromDatan.values.push({
    at: timestamp,
    value: value
});
if (fromDatan.values.length >= 50) {
    $.ajax( {
        ...
    });
    fromDatan.values = [];
};
```

Comment: Let me check and I will get back to you :)

Comment: I have added one code in an answer, The JSON is smaller (just for trial, later on bigger JSON data will be used)
But it is not pushing data as per your code. Can you please rectify where I am having trouble?